# Resharper Naming Exception for "iPhone"

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, resharper

Is it possible to add an exception to Resharper naming conventions for a specific word? In particular, I'd like to be able to make an enum value "iPhone", even though I generally prefer PascalCase for enum values.

I checked out [Resharper's naming style documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html), but didn't see any way to add a custom exception. I also tried using the custom abbreviations list, but that only works for all caps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add an exception for specific word, but there's some kind of workaround.

With ReSharper you can add more than one naming rules for a member. You can add new rule for "enum members" settings and set its name prefix to "iPhone". With this setting you'll be able to define "iPhone" enum value. Notice that with this setting you'll also be able to define "iPhoneWithReallyCoolFeature" enum value, because it doesn't violate this rule.

Screenshot for settings:

[image]

**Update:**

If you don't mind of polluting your code, you can add

```
// ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
```

just before your "iPhone" enum member.

Comment: +1, I did this for `I18n`/`i18n` for all of my settings, not just enum.