# Resharper naming convention exception for specific word

Tags: resharper

Our customer has a terminology called **A2b**, not A2B, exactly A2b.
We want to have the same name in our source code.

However, Resharper always gives warnings and proposes to use A2B.

For example: We would like to have LoadA2bData, CheckA2bAvailability instead of LoadA2BData, CheckA2BAvailability.

Is there any workaround for this?

I saw this question [Resharper Naming Exception for "iPhone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774438/resharper-naming-exception-for-iphone). But it cannot be applied for our case because A2i is not only used as prefix or postfix, but also in the middle of the names.

Comment: We cannot use `// ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming` because it appears everywhere

Answer (score 0):

[You can change the regex off resharper 7](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html) this means that you can enter a custom inspection regex. You can make a new naming style for your current project.

Comment: I don't see any regex option on that page. Just the abbreviation list. However, it does not support lowercase letter for abbreviation list or somehow it does not work for my case.